# get item from asyncstorage in constructor and pass it to other method - react native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have a file called Server.js in which I have written parent method to make get and post request. I am trying to extract few items from async-storage in the constructor and passing it to a method where I am assigning it to another variable. Now I have to use this variable inside my get and post method but unable to access the new variables(which are declared inside the constructor itself).

These new initialized variables are accessible by post method, but not inside the get method. When I tried some other workaround, it says that all my 3 variables ( participantId, mobeToken, urlAsync are undefined. Any input on my above issue.

variables :
1. **participantId**: will be sent as a header attribute (for authentication).
2. **mobeToken**: token for authentication, sent in Get request just like participantId.
3. **urlAsync**: its the url in which all the calls will be made. Once this is accessible inside Get and post method, I will remove this.baseUrl from both, Get & Post method request.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Alert,AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import axios from "axios";

const DEV_ENV_URL = "http://www.aaa.com/api";
const STAGE_ENV_URL = "http://www.bbb.com/api";
const PROD_ENV_URL = "http://www.ccc.com/api";

export default class Server extends Component {
  baseUrl = DEV_ENV_URL;

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    mobeToken1 = "";
    participantId1 = "";
    urlAsync = "";

    AsyncStorage.getItem("profile", (err, res) => {
      if (res !== null) {
        let profile = JSON.parse(res);
        participantId = profile.participantId;
      } else {
        profile = "";
      }
      AsyncStorage.getItem("mobeToken", (err, mobeToken) => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("URL", (err, Url) => {
          this.assignValues(participantId, mobeToken, Url);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  assignValues(participantId, mobeToken, Url) {
    participantId1 = participantId;
    mobeToken1 = mobeToken;
    urlAsync = Url;
    console.log("mobeToken1 "+ mobeToken1 + "," + participantId1 +"," + urlAsync);
  }

  getRequest(url) {
    // debugger;
    console.log(mobeToken1); // need variables in this method but can't
    return fetch(this.baseUrl + url , {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
      } 
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(responseJson);
        return responseJson;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        Alert.alert("", "Network connection issue. Please contact support");
      });
  }

  postRequest(url, jsonData) {
    return fetch(this.baseUrl + url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          // 'Content-Type': 'application/text',
          "parse-array": "|entryJSONList|",
          "mobeToken": mobeToken1,
          "participantId": participantId1,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(responseJson);
        return responseJson;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        Alert.alert("", "Network connection issue. Please contact support");
      });
  }
}
```

Is there any alternative solution for this?
Thanks for viewing or providing solutions to this....

Comment: Try using headers interface. Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers

Comment: The above link provided is a detailed explanation of header in fetch API..... my problem stated above is something different. Please go through my statement once to understand where I am stuck upon.

Comment: I understand your situation but have u tried console log the value before post . Is it null? If not then i thought it must be an issue with setting custom value in headers

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and it was accessible in post method.... this is why I am also confused that why this change of behavior for the same class.

Comment: @digit Issue resolved..... thanks for your concern buddy.